# Assign a keyboard shortcut to a Microsoft Excel Add-in

Tags: excel, vba, excel-addins

My friend shared a .bas file with me and told me to save it as .xlam in the vbEditor to have it as an Addin.

I've browsed in Add-ins and am able to enable it in my workbook.

Is there a way I can assign a keyboard shortcut to the Add-in? There's only one sub in that add-in file now.

I tried writing another sub with

```
Application.onKey "+^{C}" ,'Calculate'
```

But it doesn't trigger the sub to be executed.

Comment: If `Calculate` is the sub to run then you need to write `Application.onKey "+^{C}" ,"Calculate"` . Everything beginning with ' is a comment for VBA.

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand this. I thought the single quotes and the double quotes function the same like in JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't assign a shortcut to an add-in. Rather, you assign a shortcut to a *macro* - that is, a `Public Sub` procedure in your standard module.

So your code file might look like this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Calculate()
    '...code...
End Sub
```

Open it in Notepad. I'll look like this:

```
Attribute VB_Name = "Module1"
Option Explicit

Public Sub Calculate()
    '...code...
End Sub
```

Under `Public Sub Calculate()`, you want to add an attribute so that the file looks like this:

```
Attribute VB_Name = "Module1"
Option Explicit

Public Sub Calculate()
Attribute Calculate.VB_ProcData.VB_Invoke_Func = "C\n14"
    '...code...
End Sub
```

This is exactly how Excel's macro recorder assigns macro hotkeys: no need for any `Application.OnKey` work-arounds.

Save the file, import it into your VBA project: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> will now invoke that macro.

---

If you're using [Rubberduck](http://www.github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck), forget all of the above and just go to your module in the VBA editor, find the procedure and annotate it like so:

```
Option Explicit

'@ExcelHotkey("C")
Public Sub Calculate()
    '...code...
End Sub
```

Where `"C"` will make the hotkey <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>; I'd warmly recommend not using `"c"` to avoid hijacking <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (Copy).

Bring up the *code inspections* toolwindow, hit the "refresh" button; under "Rubberduck Opportunities" there should be an inspection result warning about annotations & attributes being out of sync - select "add member attribute" from the "Fix" menu, and you're done - no need to export/edit/import or deal with any obscure syntax, and if you want to change the hotkey, simply edit the comment accordingly and re-synchronize annotations & attributes.

See [VB_Attribute annotations](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/wiki/VB_Attribute-Annotations) for more information.

---

As for saving your VBA project as an add-in, simply save your VBA project's host workbook as a .xlam add-in file, then close Excel altogether and re-open it - load your .xlam from the Developer Ribbon tab's "Excel Add-ins" button (hit "Browse" to locate your .xlam file if it's not in the list).

Comment: @StasShepelev `@ExcelHotkey d` should do just that. I think the attribute value for it would be `d\n14`.

Comment: Excel VBA Editor says "Attribute ..." is a syntax error.. =|